# Deleting an indicator line with a delay after crossing

Tags: pine-script, delay, delete-row, indicator

Please help me again...
there is such indicator script...

```
//@version=5
indicator("NHNHNHNH", overlay = true)
Kol_Linii = input(2, "Количество линий")

Signal = open[3] < close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and open[1] < close[1] and close < open and high[1] > high and high[1] > close[1] and high > open

X_for_LINIA = ta.valuewhen(Signal, bar_index, 0)
Y_for_LINIA = ta.valuewhen(Signal, high, 0)

var ArrayLine = array.new_line()

if Signal
    LINIA = line.new(X_for_LINIA, Y_for_LINIA,X_for_LINIA+1,Y_for_LINIA, extend = extend.right, color = color.fuchsia, width = 1)
    array.push(ArrayLine, LINIA)
    label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(array.size(ArrayLine))+" : " + str.tostring(line.get_y1(LINIA)), color= color.white, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    
if array.size(ArrayLine) > 0
    NumberOfLine = array.size(ArrayLine) 
    Complete = false
    Index = NumberOfLine - 1
    while not(Complete)
        Line = array.get(ArrayLine, Index)
        if line.get_y1(Line) < close
            line.delete(Line)
            array.remove(ArrayLine, Index)
        Index := Index - 1
        if Index < 0
            Complete := true
```

It works great and performs the required actions, however, during the testing process, it became necessary to modify the actions of this indicator.
At the moment, the indicator controls the appearance of a certain pattern.. At the moment the pattern is formed, a line is drawn from the High ... At the moment the candle closes behind the line, the line is removed accordingly...

BUT this turned out to be not a very convenient solution ...
Help me in the concept of this script to implement the following script:

- formed a pattern
- a line is built from High
- when the line is crossed for the first time (candle closes behind the line), the line changes color (or changes its structure to broken)
- then the line remains UNTIL the CLOSING of the fifth candle after the intersection !!! - that is, after the intersection, this candle is considered the first... The rest of the candles do not matter what direction...
- then the line is removed ...

I could only make a color change after the intersection, but I can’t implement the deletion scenario after the fifth candle closes - due to my lack of competence...

Thank you...

I was able to implement only a color change, this is not presented in this script, but I cannot implement the removal with a delay of five candles...

I can't even imagine how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but works:

```
//@version=5
indicator("NHNHNHNH", overlay = true)
Kol_Linii = input(2, "Количество линий")

var BIG_NUMBER = 999999999 // safely bigger than any bar_index


Signal = open[3] < close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and open[1] < close[1] and close < open and high[1] > high and high[1] > close[1] and high > open

X_for_LINIA = ta.valuewhen(Signal, bar_index, 0)
Y_for_LINIA = ta.valuewhen(Signal, high, 0)

var ArrayLine = array.new_line()
var ArrayLineMarkForDeletionBi = array.new<int>() // array of bar indices from which we will cound deletion timeout

if Signal
    LINIA = line.new(X_for_LINIA, Y_for_LINIA,X_for_LINIA+1,Y_for_LINIA, extend = extend.right, color = color.fuchsia, width = 1)
    array.push(ArrayLine, LINIA)
    ArrayLineMarkForDeletionBi.push(999999999) // safely big number, bigger that any bar_index
    label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(array.size(ArrayLine))+" : " + str.tostring(line.get_y1(LINIA)), color= color.white, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    
if array.size(ArrayLine) > 0
    NumberOfLine = array.size(ArrayLine) 
    Complete = false
    Index = NumberOfLine - 1
    while not(Complete)
        Line = ArrayLine.get(Index)
        LineMarkBi = ArrayLineMarkForDeletionBi.get(Index)
        if Line.get_y1() < close and LineMarkBi == BIG_NUMBER
            ArrayLineMarkForDeletionBi.set(Index, bar_index)
            lb1 = label.new(Line.get_x1(), low, str.tostring(ArrayLineMarkForDeletionBi.get(Index)), color = color.yellow, style = label.style_label_up)
        if bar_index - LineMarkBi >= 5
            line.delete(Line)
            ArrayLine.remove(Index)
            ArrayLineMarkForDeletionBi.remove(Index)
        Index := Index - 1
        if Index < 0
            Complete := true
```

More elegant would be to use user-defined type and methods:

```
//@version=5
indicator("NHNHNHNH", overlay = true)
Kol_Linii = input(2, "Количество линий")

var BIG_NUMBER = 999999999 // safely bigger than any bar_index


Signal = open[3] < close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and open[1] < close[1] and close < open and high[1] > high and high[1] > close[1] and high > open

X_for_LINIA = ta.valuewhen(Signal, bar_index, 0)
Y_for_LINIA = ta.valuewhen(Signal, high, 0)


type linia
    line    ln // lines
    int     bi // bar indices
    label   lb

// by only accessing the object using this method we guarantee that the arrays will not go out of sync. Так надежнее :)
method remove(linia[] this, int id) =>
    this.get(id).ln.delete()
    this.remove(id)



var ArrayLinia = array.new<linia>()




if Signal
    LINIA = line.new(X_for_LINIA, Y_for_LINIA,X_for_LINIA+1,Y_for_LINIA, extend = extend.right, color = color.fuchsia, width = 1)
    lb = label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(array.size(ArrayLinia))+" : " + str.tostring(line.get_y1(LINIA)), color= color.white, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    ArrayLinia.push(linia.new(LINIA, BIG_NUMBER, lb))
    
if array.size(ArrayLinia) > 0
    NumberOfLine = array.size(ArrayLinia) 
    Complete = false
    Index = NumberOfLine - 1
    while not(Complete)
        Linia = ArrayLinia.get(Index)
        if Linia.ln.get_y1() < close and Linia.bi == BIG_NUMBER
            Linia.bi := bar_index
        if bar_index - Linia.bi >= 5
            ArrayLinia.remove(Index)
        Index := Index - 1
        if Index < 0
            Complete := true

plotchar(bar_index,"bar_index", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(array.size(ArrayLinia), "array.size(ArrayLinia)", "", location = location.top)
```

Comment: This is what you need...
Just great...

On the first test, everything works as it should...

I don't know how to evaluate elegance - but in my opinion it's very cool...

Super... Brilliant...

Thank you from the bottom of my heart..

Thank you...

Comment: WOW ...

Oh, I tried to figure it out - but apparently at this level of competence it is too difficult for me ...

I catch the logic, but I can’t build relationships inside the first time ...

Looks really elegant, but it's hard for me to understand

I will sort this out...